# How to remove blank line space at columnHeader of jr:table?

Tags: jasper-reports

I've been having some problems with my report. There is a table in my report that show some informations, like the image below:

[image: Informations]

However, when I generated the file, it show a blank line, like the image below:

[image: Generated file]

My table has the following code:

```
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" 
whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
    <datasetRun subDataset="ERP BD" uuid="a3124a63-2f0e-439b-8076-19e62521f2c4">
        <datasetParameter name="_IDCLIENTE">
            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{IDCLIENTEERP}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
        </datasetParameter>
        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{_ERP_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
    </datasetRun>
    <jr:column width="75" uuid="21a9bef0-6162-454f-b5a7-f2e909e86384">
        <jr:tableHeader height="10" rowSpan="1">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="75" height="10" uuid="959dff12-eff7-4c78-89d0-ccf8b817b278"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="6"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Código:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </jr:tableHeader>
        <jr:tableFooter height="10" rowSpan="1">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="75" height="10" uuid="1894ffb4-b976-428e-886e-aed2e584c4a8"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="6"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Cnpj/Cpf:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </jr:tableFooter>
        <jr:columnHeader height="10" rowSpan="1">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="75" height="10" uuid="08fa2169-87df-4588-9bee-6a423cce4153"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="6"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nome:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </jr:columnHeader>
        <jr:columnFooter height="10" rowSpan="1">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="75" height="10" uuid="4fadf9ed-3bb5-48ca-b7e3-72672d320fc5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="6"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Cidade:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </jr:columnFooter>
        <jr:detailCell height="10" rowSpan="1">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="75" height="10" uuid="0d3ca4d2-bf4d-4874-85a7-7c4ce6a463de"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="6"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[End.:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </jr:detailCell>
    </jr:column>
</jr:table>
```

All of my columns look like the column above.

How can I remove that line of my report?

Comment: `$F(EMI_FANTASIA).trim()`

Comment: @Marcelo You can try `positionType="Float"` (for End textField)  + `isStretchWithOverflow="true"` (for Name textField). More info here: [How to remove frame with empty textFields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41178070/876298) & [How to get rid of this band line in report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39977071/876298)

Comment: @AlexK I've tested your tip, but I couldn't solve my problem. However, when I moved some elements of the report, the blank line changed the position. I think I'll have to build the report again. Thanks for answer me.

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47015275/edit) question and paste the small *jrxml* to reproduce your issue

Comment: Your code does not correspond with screenshot.

Comment: I've put a little of my code. My jrxml code has more than 800 lines